# PHP: Fastest way to loop through a array / stringbuiler or something else

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, xml, csv

We have a PHP script that loops through many XML / CSV files from different websites. Right now we manage to build a good XML / CSV parser script.

The PHP script we wrote is looping though some BIG XML or CSV files. In these XML or CVS files contains Barcodes from different products.

Right now before the script starts I fill an array with the Product ID + Barcode from the MySQL like this:

```
    function Barcodes_Array() { 

    $sql = "SELECT ProductId, Barcode FROM Products WHERE (Barcode <> '') ";

    $res = mysql_query($sql);

    while ($rijen = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {      
        $GLOBALS['arrBarcodes'][] = $rijen;
    }

    }
```

Each time we loop through the XML (or CSV) files we have to check if the Barcode exists in the array and return the Product ID.

For searching in the function:

> $ProductId = SearchBarcodeProduct($EanNr, 'Barcode');

And yet the function:

```
    function SearchBarcodeProduct($elem, $field)
{
    $top = sizeof($GLOBALS['arrBarcodes']) - 1;
    $bottom = 0;

    $ProductId = 0;

    while($bottom <= $top)
    {
        if($GLOBALS['arrBarcodes'][$bottom][$field] == $elem) {         
            return $GLOBALS['arrBarcodes'][$bottom]['ProductId'];
        }
        else {

            if (is_array($GLOBALS['arrBarcodes'][$bottom][$field])) {
                if (in_multiarray($elem, ($GLOBALS['arrBarcodes'][$bottom][$field]))) {
                    return $GLOBALS['arrBarcodes'][$bottom]['ProductId'];
                }
            }

        }

        $bottom++;
    }        

    return $ProductId;
}
```

We fill in the array because it took forever each time we ask the MySQL Products Table.

My Question is now:

**It still takes a VERY long time each time looping through the array of the barcodes. Is there a faster way for any other solutions maybe a different way then a array?
Can someone help please i am working like weeks on this stupid :) thing!**

Comment: its bad practice to use `$GLOBALS` like this

Comment: Have you considered building up a list of multiple barcodes you want to look up and then when the list reaches a certain size querying for all of them at once? That would avoid the overhead of executing a new query every time but you would still benefit from MySQL's indexes.

Comment: You'll probably want to look into sorting the lookup array when it is initially loaded, and then how to perform a logarithmic search on it. (Actually, you can do the sorting part just by adding `ORDER BY barcode` to the query.)

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need 2 functions?

Try just one

```
function itemBarcode($id) { 
    $id = intval($id);
    $sql = "SELECT ProductId, Barcode FROM Products WHERE ProductId = $id Barcode <> '') ";

    $res = mysql_query($sql);

    if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {      
        return $row['barcode'];
    } else {
       return 0;
    }
}
```

**Update** if you need to search by **barcode** you can create another function:

```
function itemProduct($barcode) { 
    $sql = "SELECT ProductId, Barcode FROM Products WHERE Barcode = $barcode ";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);

    if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {      
        return $row['ProductId'];
    } else {
       return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: We dont look for the ProductID! We always look for  the Barcode thats what is universal ;)

Comment: check update. I still can't get why you need 2 functions.

Comment: The first function fills a Array so the script will lookup in the array and not 150.000 times to the database table.

Comment: that is exactly what you did: you are looping 150.000 twice. when create an array and when search in array. in my case you just get what you really need at the moment.

Comment: not really. The function Barcodes_Array() only runs at windows startup.

Comment: what do you mean by **only**? :-) Both functions run **only** when page is called :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are missing an index on your `Barcode` column in your database.. A single row lookup using a presumably unique single indexed column should be blisteringly fast.

```
CREATE INDEX Barcode_Index ON Products (Barcode)
```

Then simply:

```
SELECT ProductId FROM Products WHERE Barcode = *INPUT*
```

You could also make the index UNIQUE if you NULL the Barcode where they currently = '' if there are more than one of these.

Another option is keying the array you have with the Barcode:

```
while ($rijen = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {      
     $GLOBALS['arrBarcodes'][$rijen['Barcode']] = $rijen;
}
```

or even just:

```
while ($rijen = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {      
     $GLOBALS['arrBarcodes'][$rijen['Barcode']] = $rijen['ProductId'];
}
```

Then you can do a straight look up:

```
$ProductId = isset($GLOBALS['arrBarcodes'][$Barcode])
    ?$GLOBALS['arrBarcodes'][$Barcode]['ProductId']
    :0;
```

or:

```
 $ProductId = isset($GLOBALS['arrBarcodes'][$Barcode])
    ?$GLOBALS['arrBarcodes'][$Barcode]
    :0;
```

**N.B** Please read the warnings in the comments about use of `$GLOBALS` and `mysql_query`.

- If you need it, store the barcodes array in an object or variable instead.
- PDO is pretty handy, and I think it can also key your returned array for you on fetch.

Comment: Very strange try the both way but searching in the Table of the MySQL results more rows than the array search:

**while ($rijen = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {      
     $GLOBALS['arrBarcodes'][$rijen['Barcode']] = $rijen['ProductId'];
}**

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean.. I thought the Barcode should be unique in the database table. What is the problem? Both these options should be faster, particularly a keyed array in memory.

Comment: Just like i say. I already had the Barcode column with a Index. When i use the search for the barcode in the Products table i got more results then the $ProductId = isset($GLOBALS['arrBarcodes'][$Barcode]) ?$GLOBALS['arrBarcodes'][$Barcode]['ProductId']:0;    *** When searching for barcodes in the array ***

Comment: Hmm, strange.. is Barcode a string? You may have to normalise it to lower case with lower() when assigning the key to the array and searching.. but you would have had the same problem while loop searching. Is your array size and returned row count from the original query the same?

Comment: Maybe find and compare a few examples where the Barcode is found in the table but not the array..